# Error in linking page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I had a Problem in linking pages. Suppose, After Login from URL "/admin_1_angularjs/login.html",

the dashboard.html page should be Appear from this URL "/admin_1_angularjs/#/dashboard.html". instead it appeared in "/admin_1_angularjs/#/login.html" link. How do i fix this? here is my angularJS Controller...

```
MetronicApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
// Redirect any unmatched url
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login.html");
app.version = '1454574448';

$stateProvider.state('login', {
    url: "/login.html",
    templateUrl: 'login.html?_=' + app.version,
    controller: 'login'
    })

    .state('dashboard', {
    url:"/dashboard.html",
    templateUrl: 'views/profile/dashboard.html?_=' + app.version,
    controller: 'dashboard'
    })
```

this is my login controller.

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('login', ['$window','$scope','$timeout', function ($window,$scope,$timeout) {

$scope.hasError = false;
$scope.errorMessage = "";
$scope.input = {
    username: '',
    password: ''
};
$scope.counter = 0;
$scope.isLoading = false;
$scope.setError = function (hasError) {
$scope.hasError = hasError;
};
$scope.login = function () {
    $scope.isLoading = true;
    var postData = {
    clazz: "com.smk.aps.server.model.rpc.request.RPCAdminLogin",
      signature: "",
      data: {
  //  requestLoginID: app.uuid.v4(),
  //  requestUsername: $scope.input.username,
  //  requestPassword: CryptoJS.SHA1($scope.input.password).toString()
        }
    };



postData.data._class = postData.clazz;

$timeout(function (data,status) {
    $scope.isLoading = false;
    if ($scope.hasError = true) {
        if($scope.counter == 0) {
            $scope.errorMessage = "Invalid username or password. Error code = " + $scope.counter;
            console.log($scope.errorMessage);
            $scope.counter++;

        } else if ($scope.counter == 1) {
            $scope.errorMessage = "Server busy please try again later. Error code = " + $scope.counter;
            console.log($scope.errorMessage);
            $scope.counter++;
        } else {
            $window.location.href = "/admin_1_angularjs/";
        }
    }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Your explanation is not clear. Can you provide another ?

Comment: Can you share the code for the `login` controller? It seems like the user is being redirected to the `login` state.

Comment: shared the login controller. @gnerkus

Answer (score 0):

You have to set HTML5 mode to true to get desired result. Please refer to HTML5Mode section of following link for more details.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location